# How to set up handshake between Gitlab and Ansible

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Thanks for taking the time to read my question. I'm looking for a little direction from experience with a new workflow. We have ansible with playbooks hosted in an ec2 server and our code for project is hosted in GitLab. How can I ensure that when I make code changes and do a code commit, Gitlab CD triggers the  ansible which is hosted in ec2.

Answer (score 0):

What do your ansible do ? if you need juste to pull your code on your EC2 instance try just to write deployment code on your gitlab-ci.yml like (You should define the secret values) :

```
  deploy:
    stage: deploy
    only:
      - master
    before_script:
      - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
      - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
      - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
      - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
      - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    script:
      - ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST "cd '$DEPLOY_PATH'; git pull;"
```

Comment: My playbooks have code to deploy docker images to various environments.

Comment: Ok you can use the same code that i sent before and change script with your command line like:
- ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST "cd /folder_of_playbook;ansible-playbook ..."